# what php modules my website uses?

Tags: php, linux

I have to move fairly complex PHP website (which was not developed by me) to another server, but I'm quite sure it uses some non-default PHP modules. Is it possible to find out what those modules are without drilling through thousands of lines of code? I can get the whole list of PHP modules on current server ("php -m"), but I only need those used by my website.

Centos 5.3
PHP 5.3.8

Comment: :what you mean by php module ? extensions like GD

Comment: I mean modules that show up when you type "php -m" in console. Example: libxml, pdo_mysql, gd, json, etc.

Answer (score 1):

An absolutely un-programmatic approach would be to deploy the website, open it, look what errors show up and install the according module until you can work with the page :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to see if the functions/classes/etc... are being called.

You can try to disable them, and then test some pages.

Answer (score -1):

run an phpinfo(); from withing a file and you will see what run with your PHP

```
<?php

    phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: He is not asking this, he doesn't want the complete list of modules the server supports, just the ones the website uses.

Answer (score -1):

Im not to hot on linux yet, but phpinfo will give you all the info you should need, all the installed enabled and disabled modules.

```
<?php // Save this in any file.php and browse to it.
php_info();
?>
```

Comment: He is not asking this, he doesn't want the complete list of modules the server supports, just the ones the website uses.